# Counting total number in Excel with a specific value in cells and a single column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hope someone can help me out with what is probably quite a simple thing in Excel but I just can't seem to be able to work it out. I have a table of numbers which correspond to colour codes:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 24 |
| 36 | 36 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 24 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 36 | 2 | 36 | 2 | 2 | 24 |
| 2 | 2 | 36 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 36 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 24 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 36 | 2 |

What I would like to able to have is some way of having a total based on the criteria:

Count the total number of times '36' appears in the table only if the row has '24' in column F

I've tried using `COUNTIF` and `COUNTIFS` but that only works for matching sized columns of data.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:E7=36)*(F1:F7=24))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott! I didn't think to use SUMPRODUCT. Much appreciated!